# How does iproute2's `ip link show` determine link state?

Tags: linux, networking, iproute2

I have a network interface that `ip link show` reports like this:

```
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:43:e6:b1:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

But `/sys/class/net/docker0/flags` says this:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/docker0/flags 
    0x1003
```

The three bits that are set are `IFF_MULTICAST`, `IFF_BROADCAST` and `IFF_UP`.  This looks like an interface that is UP.  Why does `ip link` report `state DOWN`?

The system is Linux 4.15 / Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The three bits that are set are IFF_MULTICAST, IFF_BROADCAST and IFF_UP. This looks like an interface that is UP

And that corresponds perfectly well to the actual *flags* output:

```
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
                           ↑         ↑      ↑
```

> Why does ip link report state DOWN?

That's a different kind of state.

- The flag IFF_UP (shown above as "<UP>") describes *administrative* state, which is the manual knob that you can set via `ip link set eth0 up`.
- On the other hand, the "state […]" text describes *operational* state, which indicates whether the interface is *capable* of working.

Operational state is roughly the same as 'carrier' presence – e.g. Ethernet link fully established, or Wi-Fi access point associated to. A bridge is reported to be up (have a carrier) if *at least one* of its member ports is up. For that reason you may want to add a `dummy0` interface as bridge member.

Operational state roughly corresponds to the flags `IFF_LOWER_UP` (shown as "<LOWER_UP>" in the flags area) and `IFF_RUNNING` (its absence shown as pseudo-flag "<NO-CARRIER>" in your example). ([source code](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/ip/ipaddress.c#L85))

However, iproute tools obtain interface information via Netlink, and the `state …` section is printed based on the **IFLA_OPERSTATE** netlink attribute. ([source code](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/ip/ipaddress.c#L120))

This attribute is available via sysfs at `…/operstate` as well. The Linux documentation has a more detailed explanation of these flags and attributes in **[operstates.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/operstates.txt)**.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I also have an ethernet interface which `ip link` reports to have flags `BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP` but which sysfs shows to have flags 0x1003 (same as the docker0 interface above).  I guess the discrepancy is because iproute tools are not using sysfs.  Is ti reasonable to try to infer operational link state from sysfs, or is it necessary to use another interface?  I'm doing this in python and trying to avoid `subprocess.call('ip link show | grep eth0'.split()).split()` etc.

Comment: Bah, never mind, I found `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate` on my own now...

Comment: @Tom: Use the `operstate` sysfs attribute. Use a rtnetlink python module. (I have a slight suspicion that IFF_LOWER_UP is only reported via netlink butn not via sysfs.) Use `ip -json link show | jq ".[]|.operstate"` if you must...